# Why can't I use Self in match arms in trait impl block?

Tags: namespaces, rust

I can write this no problem:

```
mod sufficiently_long_namespace {
    pub enum Foo {
        Bar,
        Buzz,
        Quux,
    }
}

use std::fmt::{Display, Error, Formatter};

impl Display for sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> Result<(), Error> {
        match self {
            //-- NOTE: this works
            sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo::Bar  => write!(f, "it's Foo stuff"),
            sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo::Buzz => write!(f, "it's Buzz stuff"),
            sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo::Quux => write!(f, "it's Quux stuff"),
            //-- but this doesn't:
            // Self::Bar  => write!(f, "it's Foo stuff"),
            // Self::Buzz => write!(f, "it's Buzz stuff"),
            // Self::Quux => write!(f, "it's Quux stuff"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test1 = sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo::Bar;
    println!("{}", test1);
}
```

It compiles just fine. The commented out version using `Self`, surprisingly, doesn't:

> error[E0599]: no variant named `Bar` found for type `sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo` in the current scope

This is on `rustc 1.30.0-nightly (73c78734b 2018-08-05)`.

Did I botch my namespaces, or is it a bug indeed?

Lastly, I do want the explicit name in 
`impl Display for sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo`, but having to repeat this in `match` arms seems unwieldy.

Answer (score 2):

From IRC:

> (01:16PM) SpaceManiac: it's more of a missing feature than a bug
>   (01:17PM) SpaceManiac: consider `use long_ns::Foo;` at the top of `fmt()` then `Foo::Bar` in the match

Rust's `use` also [permits renaming](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/use.html), so I can do this:

```
    use sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo as _Self;
    match self {
        _Self::Bar  => write!(f, "it's Foo stuff"),
        _Self::Buzz => write!(f, "it's Buzz stuff"),
        _Self::Quux => write!(f, "it's Quux stuff"),
    }
```

Though this is still better:

```
    use sufficiently_long_namespace::Foo;
    match self {
        Bar  => write!(f, "it's Foo stuff"),
        Buzz => write!(f, "it's Buzz stuff"),
        Quux => write!(f, "it's Quux stuff"),
    }
```